# ImageMagick - Resize image to square

Tags: image, resize, imagemagick

I have just started doing some ImageMagick work. I am currently trying to convert an image from a file size that is almost square (1411 x 1486) or similar sizes to a square shape, like 1024x1024 unfortunately the resize function doesn't seem to do a resize of the canvas so i keep getting number like 1024x982. I am wondering if there is anyway to convert a not so square image into a square image using their c++ libraries.

The reason they are not square is because i am converting GPS positions to UTM and getting a square shape, but unfortunately because of the curve of the earth they are generally about 400m off of being square... incase you were wondering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a ! to your geometry like "1024x1024!" on the resize or create an explicit geometry for the resize method.  You may also need to set the aspect flag though the ! is supposed to do that (I've read some people have needed to do this,  don't have an explanation for you on that, though).

Comment: Note: This solution basically squeezes the image into a square shape, which might be fine for some cases, but not all the time.

Answer (score 21):

Using `1024x1024!` will not pad the thumbnail.

Here is a link to what you want
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#pad

The command line from the link (to prevent the link-rot):

```
convert -define jpeg:size=200x200 hatching_orig.jpg -thumbnail '100x100>' \
          -background skyblue -gravity center -extent 100x100 pad_extent.gif
```

Comment: Thanks! This did what I needed: convert original.png -thumbnail '64x64>' -gravity center -background transparent -extent 64x64 thumbnail.png

Comment: Note: This solution turns the image into a square by padding the center around the image with a color or with transparent space. For example, you can run: `convert -define png:size=1024x1024 my_image.png -thumbnail '1024x512>' -background transparent -gravity center -extent 1024x1024 my_image_square_padded.png` to create a center area which is 1024x512 pixels in size, padding that center area with transparent space around it. The image size will actually be 1024x1024, but the only visible part will be 1024x512 in size, because the remainder of the image is just transparent padding.

Answer (score 0):

i did as Joshua said. it worked for one image. (thanks Joshua)

i also wanted to add a solution for batch resize because

```
convert -resize 1024x1024! *.png
```

**did not worked**

---

so here there is an example command for **working sample**.

```
mkdir scaled
for %%x in (*.png) do convert -resize 1024x1024! %%x .\scaled\%%x
```

Comment: is %%x valid Bash syntax? Shouldn't it be something like $x? And are you using the same output file as the input file? If so, you should use mogrify and not convert, which doesn't work well in this situation...

Comment: in windows using %%x is ok. 
----
for the second question, there is another problem. which you give an output file becomes input files in later steps so this process takes forever. instead of this putting them into a folder is a better idea and i will edit the answer now.

Comment: @luca If you want bash you would do `for x in *.png; do convert -resize '1024x1024!' $x ./scaled/$x; done`

Comment: try mogrify for batch processing instead of convert.